# Service not responding to the c# program that uses service controller on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, windows-server-2008

I have a C# program that acts as a GUI for a windows service I created. The service can be stopped or started based on a button press from the GUI...a start button press event would call the function below. On my regular pc this code works fine. However, when I place this GUI app on my server it doesn't start or stop the service. Is there something I am missing or is there a different process for the server services vs regular pc services. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and Vista Business...Thanks in advance.

```
  public static bool StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
            if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                return true;
            else
                return false;



        }
        catch
        {
            // ...
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

First, make sure your try/catch block is logging (or otherwise notifying you) of any exceptions thrown.  Also check the servers Event Logs for errors.

Second, check permissions of the account running your program on the server.  The account may not have sufficient permissions to stop and start your service while your account on your PC did.

Comment: For the permissions - if I am able to start/stop the service in the services viewer does that mean I have sufficient permissions or do I still need to look into that?

Comment: @Jonathan I believe it does mean you have sufficient permissions. Any exceptions or anything in the Event Logs? Check the server's System log; I believe Event ID 7036 records service starts/stops.

Comment: @Jay Riggs - I looked in the log and I see somethings referring to my service but it only says that it started and stopped. I believe based on the times that those were when I stopped and started the service from the services viewer. Nothing else is there. I am going to add some output statements to the catch clause...

Comment: As an update I caught the exception and it is saying "cannot open service on computer '.'" I am googling and haven't found a definitive answer about what this actually means or what the problem could be. Is this strictly because the application does not have permissions??? or is there something else? thx

Comment: @Jonathan Is there any additional info with the exception that might provider further clues (i.e. inner exceptions)?  Is it possible that your service is exiting as soon as it's started (maybe via an exception)?  Perhaps you can download a sample service that does nothing except run and try your service starting/stopping program on that; if it works then the problem is with your service.

Comment: @Jonathan, is it possible that it is timing out? Have you tried increasing the timeout?

Comment: I figured it out. It was the account permissions. The program had to be elevated using UAC to get access to the service controller. I first right clicked and did run as administrator and that worked. So I ended up adding a manifest file to my executable that makes the UAC dialog open up at first execution asking for permission to run as admin.  Thanks a lot for the help.